# RP400N501A DC-DC regulator on PCB not outputting correct voltage

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, atmega, linear-regulator

I have created a PCB that is powered by a 3.7v lipo, and has a 5v boost converter and then a 3.3v linear regulator. The reason for the 5v boost converter is that I have to drive some LEDs at 5v, but still want to power everything else at 3.3v. With the physical PCB, when I plug in the battery, I measure 3.3V going to the ICSP header on the bottom right, but the 5v boost converter only seems to be outputting 2.8v. I think the ICSP header is getting 3.3V because the 3.3V linear regulator is still able to regulate up the 2.8V. I am unable to figure out why the 5v boost converter isn't working though.

Here are my schematic and PCB layout:
[image]
[image]

U2 is the 5v boost converter, and U3 is the 3.3v linear regulator

Comment: Is it switching at all? What does the waveform on the switch node look like?

Comment: I don't have an oscilloscope; how should I go about determining that?

Comment: The only way to determine that would be to get an oscilloscope. If you plan to do much with electronics, I highly recommend getting some kind of scope; there are some very cheap ones available now. You can find old used analog scopes on ebay for relatively cheap (as well as some $60-range handheld digital ones, but I have no idea how good quality those are), but I'd personally recommend going for one of the $400-range ones sold by companies like Rigol or Siglent if you can.

Comment: Interesting. I should be able to get access to a scope through my school tomorrow actually. Where should I probe to determine if it is switching?

Comment: The switched node of the converter, which would be the side of the inductor connected to the diode and FET.

Comment: The circuit of C2, L1, D1 and C3 needs to be close together. You have it spread all over the pcb with thin inductive tracks. Apart from being highly inefficient,it will generate a lot of RF noise. Unfortunately, your pcb layout needs a lot more attention.

Comment: "I think the ICSP header is getting 3.3V because the 3.3V linear regulator is still able to regulate up the 2.8V" Linear regulators cannot boost voltage. It just isn't possible.